# Remove all before certain delimiter starting at end of string PHP

Tags: php

Hey, I need help isolating part of a url in PHP.

say I have

http://www.test.com/something/something/important/

How could I isolate the "important"

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **[basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)** function for that.

```
echo basename('http://www.test.com/something/something/important/');
```

**Result:**

```
important
```

Comment: @Sjoerd: agreed, my previous answer was rather quick without checking it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$url ='http://www.test.com/something/something/important/';
echo basename($url);
?>
```